# Using viewbag to pass previous value to drop down list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to keep my value after a post back so I passed the value to the ViewBag in the controller. 
On my view i have something like

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" name="" id="" class="filter-select">
    <option selected value="">Topic</option>
    @{string selectedOption = ViewBag.previous;

        foreach (var topic in ViewBag.topicList)
        {
        <option value="/resources/categories/@topic" selected="@(selectedOption == topic ? "selected" : "")" >@topic</option>
        }
     }
</select>
```

however the selected value always ends up being the last value no matter what. Even when the viewbag is empty. Is there any way around this?

Comment: is there any reason you are not using Html helpers to populate dropdownlist?

Comment: I'm pretty new to MVC, if that's an easier route to go then I am all for it. Know of any good examples I can use to model my code from?

Answer (score 1):

If you put `selected` in your `option`, it is going to register as selected whether or not you assign a value to it. So what you should do is only give your option the selected attribute if it meets your criteria.

One way to do this would be:

```
<select onchange = "this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" name="" id="" class="filter-select">
    <option value="">Topic</option>
    @{string selectedOption = ViewBag.previous;

        foreach (var topic in ViewBag.topicList)
        {
            <option value = "/resources/categories/@topic" @if(selectedOption == topic) { @Html.Raw("selected"); } >@topic</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Just as a final note, it's generally preferred to use other methods than ViewBag for passing data between your Controller and View. The method I tend to use is to create a ViewModel that contains all the information the view needs, and I pass it that way.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work. It goes back to the first value, topic.

Comment: Remove the selected option from the first value. Then check to make sure that the condition `selectedOption == topic` is returning true when you want it to.

Comment: Tried that, the condition is met but its still defaulting to topic for some reason

Comment: Have you checked the html after the page loads to see if the element you expect has the `selected` attribute?

Comment: Yes, and it does not

Comment: Alright, then purely for debugging purposes, try adding an else statement after the if, and put something like `@Html.Raw("not-selected");` inside.  Then check your html and see if that is showing up on your option attributes.

Comment: My apologies Chris. Turns out I was missing the @ before Html.Raw("selected") and it turns out it is indeed needed despite the earlier @. I added that in and all appears to be working now. thanks!